# How do I convert `SInt16' to `double'?

Tags: c, type-conversion

How can I convert `SInt16` to `double` or `Float32` to `double`? I know I can convert `SInt16` to `Float32` like this:

```
double *buffer;
SInt16* frames;

for (i = 0; i < number_of_frames; i++) {
  Float32 currentFrame = frames[i] / 32768.0f;
}
```

but I'm using many C functions and I want to pass data to them in `double`.

Now I use this code:

```
for (i = 0; i < number_of_frames; i++) {

  Float32 currentFrame = frames[i] / 32768.0f;

  buffer[i] = currentFrame;
}
```

but I'm not sure the result is correct.

Comment: What makes you think that the result is "not correct" ?

Comment: @PaulR I have incorrect values at the end of whole programm. Just thought maybe something is wrong with this conversion.

Comment: simplest is just to print out a couple of values and see if it what you expected.

Comment: btw double literals are written 32768.0 without the f, adding f as suffix makes it a float, not a double.

Comment: @andrey: don't *guess* - use a debugger or add some logging code so that you can actually determine what the real problem is methodically - then you can start thinking about how to fix it. Randomly trying to "fix" things that you *think* might be part of the problem is inefficient and counterproductive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primitive C types (integers, chars, floating point types) can be inter-converted with casts. So given a signed integer value `my_signed_integer`, you can convert it to a `double` with a simple cast:

```
((double) my_signed_integer)
```

I'm guessing your `Sint16` and `Float32` are typedefs, so you can still do the same thing:

```
((double) my_SInt16_value) /* Just use this expression as a double
                              because it IS a double.  */
```

Eventually, this means:

```
for (i=0; i<number_of_frames; i++ )
  {
    buffer[i] = ((double) frames[i]) / 32768.0;
  }
```

<sup>Actually, you don't need this cast. `frames[i]` will be automatically converted to `double` because of an [implicit conversion](http://osr507doc.sco.com/en/tools/clang_conv_implicit.html).</sup>